# PHP/MYSQL - "ORDER BY" Doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a bunch of users who have a certain amount of points. I would like to arrange the users from highest points first to the lowest. However ORDER BY PTS DESC doesn't work.

```
                    <tr>
                        <th id="users_th1"><img src="<?php echo mysql_result($r_TEAMS, $i, 'LOGO'); ?>"/> <p><?php echo mysql_result($r_TEAMS, $i, 'NAME'); ?></p></th>
                        <th id="users_th2">Points Value</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                    $q_users = 'Select * from POINTS LEFT JOIN USERS on USERS.UID = POINTS.UID where TID = '.mysql_result($r_TEAMS, $i, 'TID');
                    $r_users = mysql_query($q_users, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
                    $n_users = mysql_num_rows($r_users);

                        for($k = 0; $k <$n_users; $k++){    
                    ?>



                    <tr>
                        <td class="person"><?php echo mysql_result($r_users, $k, 'NAME'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo mysql_result($r_users, $k, 'POINTS.PTS'); ?></td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: when you say "doesn't work" do you mean you get an error or the order is wrong? Also it does not seem as though you included the code with the order by.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: No I don't get an error at all, it just doesn't show it in the right order. It just displays everything at random instead of highest to lowest. When I include the ORDER BY thats when I get the error.

Comment: show your code with the order by

Comment: Show the code with the ORDER BY and the error it generates. Switch to mysqli or PDO. Organize your code so you're not doing all this processing intermixed with HTML.

Comment: I don't see an `ORDER BY` clause in your query. Also seems odd that you would left join from points to users.  I would think it would be the other way around (to get all user even if they don't have points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just guesswork, but I see you're doing a [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) between the table `USER` and the table `POINTS`. Perhaps you have a field called `PTS` in *both* tables, so if you want to order the results by that field you should indicate to which table the one you're referring to belongs.

So, do it this way,

```
$q_users = "
    SELECT *
    FROM POINTS
    LEFT JOIN USERS
    ON USERS.UID = POINTS.UID
    WHERE <table name>.TID = " . mysql_result($r_TEAMS, $i, 'TID') . "
    ORDER BY <table name>.PTS DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$q_users = 'Select * from POINTS LEFT JOIN USERS on USERS.UID = POINTS.UID where TID = '.mysql_result($r_TEAMS, $i, 'TID').' ORDER BY PTS DESC;';
```

You could also write if it won't sort or if it won't query.